# Android Gallery from URL Error

Tags: android, bitmap, inputstream, android-gallery

I'm developing an app that has a gallery for some clients. I have some urls from the images of each client. The problem is that i got no error trying to download the images, but some images fail to download/show in some devices. For example, i have one url that works on S3, but does not work on iconia tab and motorola razr.

Below there are my codes:

```
InputStream is = (InputStream) fetch(url);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FlushedInputStream(is));
Drawable img = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
```

Fetch method:

```
public Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    URL url = new URL(address);
    Object content = url.getContent();
    return content;
}
```

FlushInputStream method:

```
static class FlushedInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
    public FlushedInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
        super(inputStream);
    }

    @Override
    public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
        long totalBytesSkipped = 0L;
        while (totalBytesSkipped < n) {
            long bytesSkipped = in.skip(n - totalBytesSkipped);
            if (bytesSkipped == 0L) {
                int b = read();
                if (b < 0) {
                    break;  // we reached EOF
                } else {
                    bytesSkipped = 1; // we read one byte
                }
            }
            totalBytesSkipped += bytesSkipped;
        }
        return totalBytesSkipped;
    }
}
```

The `InputStream` is the same in both devices, but on some of them (like iconia, razr) the bitmap gets null, and on some of them (like S3), it's normal.

I got this code from google groups as a workaround for a bug that does not download all images. By the way, the `skip` is never being called in the `FlushedInputStream` method.

Is there any way to make it works in all devices? or any suggestions of another code to download the images and show them into the gallery?

Comment: print your stacktrace, error message?

Comment: There's no error message, that's the strange thing...

Comment: OK probably you are getting corrupt images, look for downloaded images in your disk with a "File Manager" and try to open.

Comment: Ok, i have downloaded the image via the android browser, and on iconia tab and razr it says the image is corrupted, but on S3 it works. I opened both with the native android gallery. Do you know why does the iconia and razr corrupt the image on download? Or do you if is there any way to download the image on the iconia and razr?

Comment: the problem is not related to devices, is mainly related to the way that we download the images, i used the FlushedInputStream method but never solved the problem.